# Moving form boxes to the left on Bootstrap and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to stylize my web application with bootstrap, but I am having an alignment problem with my form. I want the form to be left aligned with the "New Shoe" text and the header at the top of the page.

I have tried creating containers for each field and messing around with the col-md-4, but nothing seems to work.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= form.label :sku %>
        <%= form.text_field :sku, class: "form-control"%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= form.label :size %>
        <%= form.text_field :size, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= form.label :quantity %>
        <%= form.number_field :quantity, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= form.label :price %>
        <%= form.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what my page currently looks like:

[Current Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMSlp.png)

Comment: Check if there is some padding or margin between nested boxes, inspect the page with some browser developer tool to find it out. The header is not in your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing here that you have put the form partial inside a `.container` where as the title is outside of that container. Since the container and row classes add paddings and margins I would suggest that you remove the container from the form and wrap the `new` page in it.

Also boostrap form-controls should be inside a `<div class="form-group">`

Something like:

```
#new.html.erb
<div class="container">
    <h1>New Shoe</h1>
    <%= render 'form', shoe: @shoe %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', shoes_path %>
</div>


#form partial
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= form.label :sku %>
            <%= form.text_field :sku, class: "form-control"%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .row element in Bootstrap has left and right margins. It may cause this alignment problem, depending on the other elements on the page. Adding this to your custom stylesheets could work:

```
.row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

To fully understand what's going on, it would help if you could provide the code for the whole form, header included.